# Azure k8s hogging resources on VMs?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We are deploying some things on AKS and we are trying to figure out why is it by default pretty much all memory requested by system?

First we tried with a VM with 4GB ram and 3 nodes. However 90% of memory on each is pretty much taken fully. Ama-logs, ama-metrics are taking around 1350Mi, and actually only 2,2Gi is available out of 4GB.

Even lowering requests for those deployments does not seem to work, as if it is ignoring our changes for resources.

Is this even mandatory to be running and can we turn it off somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes runs services on each node and reserves a portion of the memory for these services.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-clusters-workloads#resource-reservations):

> AKS uses node resources to help the node function as part of your
> cluster. This usage can create a discrepancy between your node's total
> resources and the allocatable resources in AKS. Remember this
> information when setting requests and limits for user deployed pods.
>
> Using AKS add-ons such as Container Insights (OMS) will consume
> additional node resources
>
> Memory utilized by AKS includes the sum of two values.
>
> - The kubelet daemon is installed on all Kubernetes agent nodes to manage container creation and termination. By default on AKS, kubelet
>   daemon has the memory.available<750Mi eviction rule, ensuring a node
>   must always have at least 750 Mi allocatable at all times. When a host
>   is below that available memory threshold, the kubelet will trigger to
>   terminate one of the running pods and free up memory on the host
>   machine.
> - A regressive rate of memory reservations for the kubelet daemon to properly function (kube-reserved).
>
>   - 25% of the first 4 GB of memory
>   - 20% of the next 4 GB of memory (up to    8 GB)
>   - 10% of the next 8 GB of memory (up to 16 GB)
>   - 6% of the next 112 GB of memory (up to 128 GB)
>   - 2% of any memory above 128 GB
>
> The above resource reservations can't be changed.
>
> For example, if a node offers 7 GB, it will report 34% of memory not
> allocatable including the 750Mi hard eviction threshold.
>
> 0.75 + (0.25*4) + (0.20*3) = 0.75GB + 1GB + 0.6GB = 2.35GB / 7GB = 33.57% reserved
>
> In addition to reservations for Kubernetes itself, the underlying node
> OS also reserves an amount of CPU and memory resources to maintain OS
> functions.

Comment: This math does not add up.
The node has 4 GB, so 1.8 is not allocable by default, only 2.2 can be allocated. And out of that 2.2 allocable 90% is reserved by services of kube-system.
So out of 4 GB of VM, I have around 200Mi to allocate.

Based on documentation I should have at least 2.2?